# PHP MYSQL запрос

Tags: php, mysql

Есть две таблицы

1. Таблица содержит в себе все разделы и категории и имеет вид uid|category|razdel - где uid это уникальный идентификатор категории, category это русское название, razdel соответственно тоже русское название раздела.
2. Таблица это новости с кучей полей но главная в ней это uid (только тут он уже catEN нфзывается)

Мне нужно вывести по 5 новостей из каждой категории принадлежащей одному разделу.

В данный момент все работает но очень коряво, получается массив в массиве и страница генерируется больше 1.5 сек

```
    $c = mysql_query("SELECT uid,nameRU FROM category WHERE nameEN='$razdel'");
if(!$c) exit('Ошибка');
    while   ($cat=mysql_fetch_assoc($c))
    {
        $r = mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM news WHERE catEN='".$cat['uid']."' order by mktime DESC LIMIT 5");
            if(!$r) exit('Ошибка2');
            while   ($dt=mysql_fetch_assoc($r))
            {
            }
    }
mysql_free_result($c);
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте 1 запрос с конструкцией `JOIN` в `sql` запросе.
возможно поможет?

```
SELECT news.* FROM category 
LEFT JOIN news ON news.catEN=category.uid
WHERE category.nameEN='$razdel'
ORDER BY mktime DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

UPD:
Ссори, проглядел, тогда можно выбрать без лимита, и перекинуть на php задачу выборки 5 новостей из категории, упорядочив новости по категориям. php в любом случае сделает это быстрее, чем посылка нескольких запросов в БД:

```
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT news.* FROM category 
    LEFT JOIN news ON news.catEN = category.uid 
    WHERE category.nameEN = '$razdel' 
    ORDER BY сategory.uid, mktime DESC";

    $res = array();//результат
    $j=0; //счетчик новостей в категории

    if ($result = mysqli_query($link,$query)){
        $res[0]=$result[0];
        for($i=1;$i<count($resut);$i++){
            if($result[$i]['catEN']==$res[count($res)-1]['catEN']){
                if($j++<5) $res[]=$result[$i];
            } else {
                $j=0
                $res[]=$result[$i];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Нее, так он всего 5 новостей выведет а необходимо по 5 из каждой категории, потому что в Разделе примерно 5-7 категорий.

Comment: Спасибо, хотя не совсем то о чем думал но в какую сторону копать понял!

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать сделать с помощью хранимой процедуры и курсора - заморочится)

Но я бы вам вот что посоветовал - если будет много новостей, то такой вариант никуда не годится - будет сильно жутко тормозить - нет смысла тащить с сервака данных на 1000 строк - если в итоге нужны к примеру всего 50.

Вот мое предложение - добавьте таблицу `last_news` - со след колонками

```
id - содержащию ссылку на news.id 
cat_id- категория category.uid.
```

они и будут содержать готовые данные - то есть вы будете просто брать данные из этой таблицы. 
Теперь поясню как данные приготавливать:  логично что данные будут меняться только при 2-ух действиях - добавлении новости и ее удалении. Поэтому при наступлении этих действий мы выполняем следующие действия:

- удаляем из таблицы `last_news` все `id` при условии что `cat_id` равна категории новости которую мы добавили или удалили.
- После вставки /удаления новой новости - делаем запрос на получение списка 5 последних новостей категории новости которую мы добавили или удалили. Этот запрос у вас есть.
- И последние действие - мы вставляем в таблицу `last_news` строки с `id`  равными `id` полученные при п2 (предыдущее действие) а `cat_id` у всех строк равна категории новости которую мы добавили или удалили.

Вот впринципе и все, кстати пункт 2 и 3 можно сделать одним запросом